# Drawing on Argand Diagram

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I know what $a : \{z \in \mathbb{C}: | z + 2 | + | z - 2 | = 10 \}$ looks like?

I tried expanding it with $z = x + iy$, but I end up with a circle radius $1$ (which is clearly wrong!)

Comment: You may recall that the curve consisting of all points the sum of whose distances from $2$ points is constant is an ellipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can do it using the approach you started. The term $|z+2|$ is the distance from the point $z=x+iy$ to the point $-2$. This is $\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}$. We have a similar expression for $|z-2|$, and arrive at the equation 
$$\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2}=10.$$
Now we manipulate. A routine thing to do (one can do better) is to rewrite the equation   as $\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}=10-\sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2}$ and square both sides. There is some nice cancellation, and we end up with 
$$5\sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2}=25-2x.$$
Square both sides again. Note that the coefficient of $x$ disappears.

**Remark:** Things are much quicker, and nicer, if we are familiar with the **geometric** theory of the ellipse.  Recall that an ellipse is the locus of points the sum of whose distances from two given points is constant. Here the two points, in Cartesian coordinates, are $(-2,0)$ and $(2,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

It is an ellipse.  The condition is that the sum of the distances from $z$ to $2$ and from $z$ to $-2$ are exactly $10$.